# Execute an electron app within vscode extension

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, electron

I'm working on a vscode extension and it need to execute a external program to do different task. If the external program takes no arguments: UI pop. With cmd line arguments: cmd line mode. I've build this application using electron and it work well in debug and when launching it with electron on the cmd line. It was package to a .exe on Windows and works equally well in cmd line or directly double clicking it.

Thing gets bad when I try to execute it from my vscode extension with child_process.execFile. I just put the exe path, and the process stays in the task monitor (no UI). I put some cmd line arguments: node reply: bad option. I've try to run it within a tools.bat file, so that I call the bat instead. Does not work either. I've try with fork, spawn, exec. Same behavior.

Launch code:

```
      const childProcess = child.execFile(pathToExec, [], { cwd: execDir, env: process.env, });

      childProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data.toString());
      });
      childProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data.toString());
      });
      childProcess.on("exit", () => {
        console.log("exit");
      });
```

Note: The same code with a normal executable build with Visual Studio in C# for example, works well if I launch it with exec. We just wanted to use electron with JS so that the team feel right at home.

Comment: Does `pathToExec` contain any spaces? Does this work if you add `shell: true` to the `exec` options?

Comment: no space on my pc (thought I can't garantee the path that the client will use). I've try exec with shell to "cmd.exe". Same result. Curiously when I try to run it with "electron main.js" (so no packaged exe) it works but it crashes to "app.on", telling me app is undefined (const {app} = require('electron')). This of course happen only in the vs code extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I meet the same problem.I search the solution for a long time,finally I find [this page](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/3011),it shows that it's the problem of vscode process's environment.so you should create new process by this mode:

```
var spawn_env = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(process.env));
console.log(process.env);
delete spawn_env.ATOM_SHELL_INTERNAL_RUN_AS_NODE;
delete spawn_env.ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE;
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
spawn(cmd,[],{env:spawn_env,detached:true});
```

If not work,please modify your `.vscode/tasks.json` in your extension project:

```
"version":"your version"
"options": {
    "env":{//add this element
    }
},
...
...
```

Hope it can work!

Comment: Did not have the time yet to try it as I switch to by C# solution. Will keep you posted soon.

Comment: OMG... it works! (sorry for the late response, I've been very busy lately!)

Comment: Damn, it took me a while to figure out my app would not launch because it is an Electron app.
I eventually passed an empty env: spawn(cmd, args, {env: {}})

Comment: Update: don't just pass an empty dict like I said above, it won't work on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that could help you along:

- When you pass Command Line Options to a packaged Electron application, you need to append `--` before any of your other options. This signals electron that these command line options are in fact meant for your application, and not the Electron/Node executable

  `exampleApp.exe -- --yourOption1`
- Secondly, you're attempting top spawn a synchronous process with childProcess.execFile(). childProcess.execFile() also has some know security issues, which is why you should avoid it. Instead, use an asynchronous childProcess.spawn() or even childProcess.fork() for enabled Inter-Process Communication. [Here is an excellent article](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-execfile-spawn-exec-and-fork-in-node) that goes into more detail concerning the different methods of childProcess.

Comment: Yeah I did read that article. Thing is I try with every possible function: exec, execFile, spawn and fork. None of them works. Btw thank for the '--' comment this should clarify at least why I've got the "bad option" sometimes. Still the app does not run at all (or run in the background no UI).

Comment: Do you have any precedence for spawning another Electron App from a VS Code Extension? I have no experience with VS Code Extension authoring, but .. you know, you're already inside an Electron instance, why spawn another?

Comment: No first time doing this. This is mainly because I need to spawn a more complex UI with form, inputs, text area within vscode and I did not see a way to do that easely inside an extension.

Comment: Just made a equivalent in C# .net. Works flawlessly. There is something with electron that I do not understand :(

Comment: So, calling your packaged executable now works from the command line? How about attempting to call it from a seperate Node.js process?

Comment: It did always work cmd line or directly in windows (double click). Even without the -- (as I understand it when you run packaged exec within a cmd shell you don't need the --, the -- is needed when calling it like a node task -> like: node main.js). Anyway, the exec works perfectly outside of the vscode environment. Once inside everything goes down the drain. My C# equivalent, works in every case. It must something that has do to with invoking an electron process withing an electron process.

Answer (score 0):

Try `vscode.env.openExternal(vscode.Uri.file(filePath));`
But I have a problem in Linux ([VSCode extension can't start external Electron application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66983944/vscode-extension-cant-start-external-electron-application)).